# Resource Group and Resource itself in different region

Tags: azure, azure-resource-group

Can I create a resource **"myproject"** in region **India**, but create a kuberenetes cluster in uswest region ?

If this is possible then what is point specifying Region for resource group ?

Answer (score 3):

Terminology:

> **resource group** - A container that holds related resources for an Azure solution. The resource group includes those resources that you want to manage as a group. You decide which resources belong in a resource group based on what makes the most sense for your organization.

and

> When creating a resource group, you need to provide a location for that resource group. You may be wondering, "Why does a resource group need a location? And, if the resources can have different locations than the resource group, why does the resource group location matter at all?" The resource group stores metadata about the resources. When you specify a location for the resource group, you're specifying where that metadata is stored.
>
> Source: [What is Azure Resource Manager?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/overview)

And then there's also this:

> **What is an Azure resource group?**
>   Each resource in Azure must belong to a resource group. A resource group is simply a logical construct that groups multiple resources together so they can be managed as a single entity *based on lifecycle and security*. For example, resources that share a similar lifecycle, such as the resources for an n-tier application may be created or deleted as a group. Put another way: everything that is born together, gets managed together, and deprecates together, goes together in a resource group.
>
> Source: [Resource access management in Azure - What is an Azure resource group?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/govern/resource-consistency/resource-access-management#what-is-an-azure-resource-group)

The most important information to take away from this:

- **A resource group is nothing more than a logical grouping of Azure resources**
- **Everything that is born together, gets managed together, and deprecates together, goes together in a resource group**

**EDIT:**
If you *do* want a solution that prohibits users from creating resources in specific regions, or would like to limit the allowed regions, have a look at [Azure Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/overview).

You can find an example here: [azure-policy/samples/built-in-policy/allowed-locations/](https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/tree/master/samples/built-in-policy/allowed-locations)

> This policy enables you to restrict the locations your organization can specify when deploying resources. Use to enforce your geo-compliance requirements. Excludes resource groups, Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory/b2cDirectories, and resources that use the 'global' region.

Comment: does that mean Resource Group and Resources need not be in Same Region ? Please confirm

Comment: Confirmed, have done so numerous times. The second quote contains the question "if the resources can have different locations than the resource group, why does the resource group location matter at all?"

Comment: yes - I have a point on 2nd quote. Why not make resource a global thing / entity ?

Comment: That's a question on the internal design of Azure, SO is not the place for that...